# How to execute a Helm chart using any API

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

We are trying to make a single click deployment of an application using helm chart on one cluster from remote but we are not getting any any suitable way for this, We have tried with Pyhelm also but it dosnot support latest helm. Could anyone have already came across this scenario.

We do have the application helm chart in one of our cluster and we want to execute that helm chart for that we are looking for API.

Answer (score 0):

ArgoCD may be what you're looking for:

- GitHub: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd
- Docs: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- Demo: https://cd.apps.argoproj.io/applications?proj=&sync=&health=&namespace=&cluster=&labels=
- ArgoCD + Helm docs: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/

Their UI is pretty efficient, includes with multi-cluster management options, external directory integration, ...

While if you're looking for an API: ArgoCD uses Kubernetes CRD, allowing you to describe your application deployments as "Applications", or "ApplicationSets". Your application could integrate with some Kubernetes cluster API, configuring ArgoCD and tracking its applications.